# Is there any shortcut for a boolean function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I know in PHP or Java you can do something like this

```
int usefulCharacters = text == null ? 0 : text.length();
```

So in Python i want to check if after using the filter(item,iterable) function and return true if item is appeared in the iterable:

Note: valid_indices is in rdd format so i have to convert it into a list so it will be iterable

```
is_index1 = (filter(index_md5,valid_indices.collect()) ? true:false)
```

Seems like Python doesn't like the "?" syntax though. Please advise, i'm learning Python and thank you!

Comment: This answered my question already, thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, the ternary operator is using syntax :
`True if <condition> else False`

so, Following your code sample, it will give:

```
is_index1 = True if filter(index_md5,valid_indices.collect()) else False
```

Note that I also use the `True` and `False` values to use Python language booleans.

Comment: the syntax is good but i need to tweak a little bit inside of the if condition to make it works properly. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for this (`df` being PySpark data frame, and not `RDD`)

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, size

Res=df.select(F.when(F.col('text').isNull(), lit(0)).otherwise(F.size(F.col('text'))).alias('new_col'), <other columns>)
```